# Complete yum history

Tags: linux, history, yum

When I run `yum history` I get a list of the last 20 yum operations. If I didn't clean my history, is there a way to get a full list?

Does yum only keep track of the last 20 operations? Is there a setting similar to bash that lets you keep more?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
cat /var/log/yum.log
```

## edit:

Also, after reading about yum history, it seems it keeps everything also in a sqlite db. This means that you have access to all the info you want from any time.

Try to run somehitng like:

```
yum history package-list \*yum\*
```

You can list all transactions with:

```
yum history list all
```

After that you can check, based on date or what ever you want happened in a specific transaction:

```
yum history list 107
```

or about a specific package:

```
yum history package-list \*glib\*
```

## edit2:

http://yum.baseurl.org/wiki/YumHistory

## edit3:

It seems this question was also already ansewred and is in the first page of google search:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/63381/how-to-list-all-the-installed-package-in-fedora-with-the-time-of-the-installatio

Comment: It gives the full list of yum operations. Also it keeps everything from the first install if you don't do any logrotate. Have no idea why you don't like it.

Comment: @cristi `yum.log` shows the files that were affected by yum operations. Is there a file that provides the same information as `yum history`, but with older entries?

Comment: It keeps packages affected, not files.